# Linker error (LNK2005) when using AMD's Vulkan Memory Allocator

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2017, vulkan

I have just started using AMD's VMA by including `vk_mem_alloc.h` in my header file with `#define VMA_IMPLEMENTATION` before it. But when I build the project, a lot of `LNK2005` error appear.

My file structure is like

`VulkanBase`( .h + .cpp ) -(Base class of)-> `ExApp` (.cpp)

I have declared this library in `VulkanBase.h` file. The errors are like all the members in `vk_mem_alloc.h` have already defined in `ExApp.cpp`. At the end of the error list, it showed that `one or more multiply defined symbols found`.

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do include the VulkanBase.h file in multiple cpp files? If yes You shouldn't add the mentioned #define. It should (probably) be placed only in one cpp file just before the VMA header is included.

Comment: But my VMA implementation exists in both .cpp file. Is there other solution?

Comment: You can include the vk_mem_alloc.h file in many cpp files. But only in one of these cpp files You should place the #define VMA_IMPLEMENTATION. At least that's how many of the single-header libraries work. I didn't use the VMA but I think it should be used in a similar way.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do is to include `vk_mem_alloc.h` in `VulkanBase.h`, and before the line `#include "VulkanBase.h"` in `VulkanBase.cpp`, add `#define VMA_IMPLEMENTATION`:

#### VulkanBase.h

```cpp
#include "vk_mem_alloc.h"

// declarations here
```

#### VulkanBase.cpp

```cpp
#define VMA_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "VulkanBase.h"

// definitions here
```

This way only one implementation of VMA exists and is compiled in `VulkanBase.cpp`. You can then include the `VulkanBase.h` file in other .cpp and .h files, which then only contains declarations for VMA. Hope that helps.